# Apex Grid Record Selector

Tags: visualforce

I'm new to Salesforce and VisualForce pages. Is there a apex control that I can use to give me the same functionality as the built in (LineItemView?) multi record selector and filtering capabilities that are in the screen shot below?

[image]

Basically I wan to duplicate that functionality for selecting child records.

Comment: Wrapper class can help in this case.https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Wrapper_Class

Comment: You can find 2 ways for implementation this functionality [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14823107/how-to-find-out-which-checkboxes-have-been-selected-on-the-next-page-in-visualfo/14825189#14825189